# Can a (vanilla) Kalman Filter's Observation Matrix $H_k$ depend on the state vector $x_k$?

Tags: kalman-filters

A vanilla [Kalman Filter](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/) allows for a *time varying* observation matrix $H_k$. Is it allowable for $H_k$ to be a function of the system state $x_k$ in a vanilla Kalman filter?

First, am I correct that this is not allowed in the vanilla Kalman filter? If it is allowed, then I don't understand how measurements would then act to correct the parameters of $x$ that predict them via $H_k$. I'd appreciate a more explicit description of this than my own hunch though!

Second, am I correct that the Extended Kalman Filter & the Unscented Kalman Filter *do explicitly allow* for this situation? If I am, do these filters allow observations to correct the terms of $x$ that are predicting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-linear system model that the unscented and extended Kalman filters work with (omitting control) is the following:
$$x_{k+1} = F(k, x_k, v_k) \\ y_k = H(k, x_k, n_k)$$
where $F$ is the state transition function and $H$ is the observation function.  The linear Kalman filter is just the special case where $F$ and $H$ have the form:
$$ F(k, x, v) = A_k x + v \\ H(k, x, n) = B_k x + n$$ for sequences of matrices $A_k$ and $B_k$.  In particular, the functions $F$ and $H$ are linear.

The following is a bit of a pedantic distinction (particularly in the non-linear case) but while the expression $F(k, x_k, v_k)$ clearly depends on $x_k$, the function $F$ *itself* does not.  In the non-linear case this is no limitation.  In the linear case, if the matrix $B_k$ depended $x_k$ then the function $H$ would no longer be linear.

Comment: Thank you – this formalises how I thought it probably was.

Comment: Incidentally – I originally used "linear" Kalman filter, then edited it to be "vanilla". I think linear would be the correct term, and I should revert to use that?

Comment: For me, "Kalman filter" by itself unambiguously means the linear case.  I was a little hesitant about using "linear Kalman filter" as it makes it sound like there is a non-linear Kalman filter where there are non-linear *generalizations* of the Kalman filter.  I don't think there's a strong reason to change the wording.